# Testing a function that only calls one or two other functions

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

## The short version

### The code

As part of TDD, we often end up with functions that follow this pattern:

```
function onSendRequestForSelected() {
    this.deselectStepsWithRequest();
    this.sendRequestForSelected();
}
```

Each of the internally called functions has their own unit tests.

### The tests

Our unit tests for this function end up pretty much ensuring the function body calls were made:

```
expect( iStep.deselectStepsWithRequest ).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect( iStep.sendRequestForSelected ).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

### The problem

The problem is:

- Our tests end up testing **function calls** rather than **behaviour**.
- We're unsure what is exactly the **purpose** of these tests - they protect from nothing other than any future changes.
- Nor do they serve as a **design** documentation.
- They clearly test the **how** rather than **what**.

---

## The long version

### Starting point

We start with the test:

```
it( 'should send a request for each of the selected steps', ... )
```

And then implement:

```
function onSendRequestForSelected() { ... }
```

So far so good.

### New requirement, refactoring

Then we realise we need to deselect steps that already have a request.

So we refactor:

```
it( 'should send a request for each of the selected steps', ... )
```

becomes the test for

```
function sendRequestForSelected() { ... }
```

and create

```
it( 'should deselect steps that already has a request', ... )
```

implemented by

```
function deselectStepsWithRequest() { ... }
```

### The rubbish test

and then introduce:

```
function onSendRequestForSelected() {
    this.deselectStepsWithRequest();
    this.sendRequestForSelected();
}
```

but no idea how to test it.

```
it( 'should send a request for each of the selected steps', ... )
```

makes little sense as the test itself only ensure a function is called.

```
it( 'should call sendRequestForSelected()', ... )
```

seems like a rubbish test.

## The question

So it seems you end up with two options, neither is ideal. Which one is better?

Given TDD we start with:

```
it( 'should deselect steps that already has a request', ... )
it( 'should send a request for each of the selected steps', ... )

function onSendRequestForSelected() {
    ...
}
```

### Option 1

```
it( 'should deselect steps that already has a request', ... )
it( 'should send a request for each of the selected steps', ... )

function onSendRequestForSelected() {
    this.deselectStepsWithRequest();
    this.sendRequestForSelected();
}
```

Problems:

- The actual sub-functions are not tests (if they would they would be redundant). Dangerous if they will be reused (consider them being needed by other functions).

### Option 2

```
// No test

function onSendRequestForSelected() {
    // Test for each of the following
    this.deselectStepsWithRequest();
    this.sendRequestForSelected();
}
```

Problems:

- This is not really TDD; this is not how we started.
- No test to serve as a design documentation. We do not define the behaviour.

## In graphical form

[image: A diagram showing function 1 calling sub 1 and 2, while function 2 calling sub 2 and 3]

Where do you drop the tests?

- Testing F1 and F2 only will yield redundant tests for S2.
- Testing for S1, S2, and S3 will not test for the behaviour of F1 and F2.

Comment: Related: [Should unit tests be written for getter and setters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197370/should-unit-tests-be-written-for-getter-and-setters)

Comment: "in both cases, each of the internally called functions has their own unit tests". Why? Avoid testing internal functions as they are implementation details. Test just the public APIs and your problem goes away.

Comment: @DavidArno Good point. A) Because sometimes there quite a few permutations for each sub-function but these are independent; so it's easier to test each separately. B) Sometimes the sub-functions are reusable (called by more than one function) and there's always the chance such will be a future case (although the solution for this will be to make the sub-functions internal - closure or scope - to the calling function).

Comment: Honestly, where is the question in your question? Seems you have already understood your situation very well, now stop writing useless unit tests.

Comment: @DocBrown That's good to know. I've added 'The question' section, also showing a graphical expression of the problem.

Comment: @gnat To which the widely accepted answer is **no**. This is a rather different case - it's about where to test so we test for the right thing within TDD context, not whether or not to test.

Comment: as far as I can tell, [the answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/130926/31260) over there says "Test everything that could possibly break..."

Comment: @gnat, that satisfies the **defence** part of TDD, not the **design** or **documentation** part. It's all good and dandy if you write tests after your code, but if you start with tests you often run into these troubles.

Comment: the other part of your question appears to be asked and answered already many times before. See eg [Relationship between TDD and Software Architecture/Design](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/244451/31260)

Comment: Well, as already have being said, this question can come with some potentially controversial topics. But here is my opinion, heavily based on self experience.

I think that when you come with a new method that just call other two public ones (I'm inferring the `public` part here since they are already unit tested), like in your example, you are trying to convey a business domain idea, rather than a "implementation detail" which probably is covered by the other two methods.

In this context, maybe make sense to test this method in a more integration manner.

Answer (score 3):

This is obviously a controversial topic.

Having consulted a multitude of opinions, the conclusion is that this is correct:

Given the method

```
function onSendRequestForSelected();
```

and its pre-implementation tests:

```
it( 'should deselect steps that already has a request', ... )
it( 'should send a request for each of the selected steps', ... )
```

the eventual implementation shall be:

```
function onSendRequestForSelected() {
    this.deselectStepsWithRequest();
    this.sendRequestForSelected();
}
```

and the eventual tests shall be:

```
it( 'should deselect steps that already has a request', function(){
    expect( iStep.deselectStepsWithRequest ).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

it( 'should send a request for each of the selected steps', function(){
    expect( iStep.sendRequestForSelected ).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

## Reasoning

Much of the reasoning behind this is based on my argument [why you should write a test for every method (well nearly), including setters and getters](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/302922/130377).

In short:

- TDD is not only about defence, but also **design** and **documentation**.
- For design and documentation purposes, tests shall be written before implementation.

  - This is a fundamental principle of TDD so it may sound elementary.
  - But the question needed to be asked is: "**Can someone implement this part of the system based on the provided tests**?".
  - So if there is no test, there will be no implementation.
- Test are subject to **refactoring** and **extractions** much as implementation code is.

## Test extraction

So basically, the expect line here:

```
it( 'should deselect steps that already has a request', function(){
    expect( iStep.deselectStepsWithRequest ).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

is a way of saying:

> The test condition, instead of being satisfied here will be satisfied by calling `deselectStepsWithRequest()`

(for which there is a separate test).

## Is like code extraction

much in a way `this.deselectStepsWithRequest()` in here:

```
function onSendRequestForSelected() {
    this.deselectStepsWithRequest();
}
```

is a way of saying

> Instead the execution code being here, it is in `deselectStepsWithRequest()`.

Comment: IMHO, if this is the correct answer to your question depends on if you are a "true TDD believer", or if you believe that software development is more efficient when you do not apply 100% TDD.

Comment: @DocBrown Not sure what 100% TDD means, but I definitely don't suggest that 100% test coverage is a viable aim; this has nothing to do with test coverage. The most important point is that people stop looking at tests as defence mechanism only - for this you don't need TDD, you can write tests as an afterthought.

Comment: @Izhaki: Aren't you now testing an implementation detail instead of what should happen? A better test would be setting up a list of requests, calling the method, and checking that the proper items were deselected, and the proper requests were made (possibly mocking the actual making of the requests/actual deselecting). You do not want to test that a function knows who to delegate to, but that it gets the job done.

Comment: @SjoerdJobPostmus. One way to look at this is that you do end up testing an implementation detail for the sake of ensuring proper documentation and removing what would otherwise be unnecessary test redundancy (remember that in this case the whole equals its parts). But another way is a simple logical argument where **Given X and Y, T will hold**. Whether X is delegated (making it an implementation detail) or not is not important - what's important is that **T holds**.

Comment: @Izhaki: yes. But the **T** that must hold is of the form "items are no longer selected and requests have been made", not "I have asked somebody to deselect them and I have asked somebody else to do requests". Given the test you described, I still have to look up the separate tests to see what actually happens. For a great talk which is somewhat relevant, watch https://vimeo.com/68730418 ("467 tests, 0 failures, 0 confidence" by Katrina Owen).

Comment: @SjoerdJobPostmus Can't help responding to the latter argument with whether the same cannot be applied to code? If you need to implement function T and in order to do so you call functions X then Y, does this mean you didn't implement the function? After all people still need to look at X and Y to see how the function is implemented. And your first argument is slightly misleading: since the second clause can be replaced by "I'm sure that asking somebody else will mean it will get done" (for both cases).

Comment: @SjoerdJobPostmus. Having watched the video: A) "Assert that outgoing command messages actually get sent" (7:02). B) "The scaffolder isn’t delegating the file system interaction to some other object it is micro-managing the process…" (14:35). Both of these seem to support my argument. Did you mean this or am I missing something?

Comment: Roy Osherov gives the following definition of 'unit': "the sum of actions that take place between the invocation of a public method in the system and a single noticeable end result by a test of that system. A noticeable end result can be observed without looking at the internal state of the system and only through its public APIs and behaviour." Based on this definition, I think it's right to assert that `deselectStepsWithRequest()` and `sendRequestForSelected()` are called, provided that they are publicly accessible methods (if they aren't, the test shouldn't be able access them anyway).

Comment: A follow-up to my previous comment – if the two methods were private, then I would instead want to assert on whatever API or behaviour of the system *is* publicly accessible. For instance, if `deselectStepsWithRequest()` in turn calls a public API (or in some other way causes a publicly observable behaviour) then I would assert on that API or behaviour.

Comment: One more cheeky follow-up! :) I think it's entirely reasonable to break up a larger **public** function into multiple smaller **private** sub-functions and so on, while only testing the public function. As long as you're thoroughly testing all **units of behaviour**, as defined above, you can still write clear, focussed and well structured unit tests. Your tests need only call the public function and assert on the return and/or side-effects; they don't need to know how that function works internally, e.g. what it calls. Unit tests shouldn't prevent you from using encapsulation and subroutines.