# unit testing a mocked class

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm currently writing unit tests for my PHP code. I've read that unit tests should not interract with external elements such as network and filesystem.

In my code i have a curl wrapper class to simplify curl calls (i just use `$response = CurlWrapper::call($url)`) For my tests, i added a mock to replace this wrapper. my mock class returns predefined response based on the url. This way i avoid HTTP response times and my tests does not rely on an externaressource which can change at any moment.

Do i need to unit test my curl wrapper (the original one, not the mock) and if i need to, how can i test it ?

Comment: the question you linked is very interesting and i learned some useful things. However, i'm not fully sastisfied with the answer : in my case, the curl wrapper does more than just calling the curl library (not a lot of things but there is a little logic in the class). So does this wrapper needs to be tested in a unit test or is an integration test enough ?

Comment: that seems to be addressed by an [answer in another related question](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/130926/31260): "Test everything that could possibly break..."

Comment: well i think i have an answer with all these related questions. i'm still not absolutely convinced that what i chose to do is the best answer but it seems that there is no universal answer as the limit between unit and integration test is very tiny

Comment: An integration test tests the interaction between objects.  If you're using mocks, it's not an integration test.