# Dry refactoring against database

Tags: orm, dry

Our database has an `Attribute` table and a `WorkItem` table that are in a many to many relationship using a `WorkItemAttribute` table. The `WorkItemAttribute` table contains the foreign keys for each and a `value` column specifying the value of the associated attribute.

I wrote a simple CRUD web api and tests dealing with the `WorkItemAttribute`s on a per `WorkItemID` basis using an ORM provider.

I was then tasked with doing the same for an `EnvelopeAttribute` table, which is the same as the `WorkItemAttribute` table but has a foreign key to an `Envelope` table instead.

I can duplicate everything I wrote for the first ticket, and change all the occurrences of "Envelope" to "WorkItem", but it really bugs me doing so.

Is there any way to refactor the shared logic when all the class names are different, even at the ORM level?

Comment: Which programming language and which ORM are you using?

Comment: @ Doc Brown We're using .Net Core C# and Entity Framework Core

Comment: Frankly, these kinds of tests may not be the best use of your time.  See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/130925/should-we-test-all-our-methods

Comment: @RobertHarvey the update operation at least has some extra constraints like it needs to validate if the specified record exists and create a warning in our database log table if not for each record specified. That and I'm under utilized at this company so writing tests gives me something to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a generic type

```
IItemRepository<T>
{
     T GetAttributeById(string id);
}
```

But you may find you have to use reflection, either to get the Id or map to the object.

Sometimes its best just to do the extra typing

Comment: I made my *attribute proxy classes inherit from an abstract class, and ended up going with the generic interface `IAttributeCRUD<T> where T: abstractParent` this ended up being much cleaner